# Displaying DataGridView selected item in text box

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have following code which I used to display datagridview selected value in text boxes of the same interface. Now I want to display ID of the selected row in a text box of ANOTHER interface. I simply changed the form name. But it does not display the value in text box and do not give any error also.To check whether the code gets executed I temporarily put a messagebox withing if condition and checked. The messagebox got displayed. Please help

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    If i >= 0 Then
        Reservation.txtBoxCustProfileID.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Empty Row Clicked")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you showing the other form? What happens if you add `Reservation.Show()` after setting the value.

Comment: @Fruitbat : You made my day.It worked.Thank you